connection could not be created and invalid database URL
I see the following error message when I try to execute the liquibase validate command
Validating Liquibase Script on Target Database
Unexpected error : connection could not be created to JDBC:db2://hostname..
[Error][e][10005][4.33.31] Invalid database URL syntax: jdbc:db2://hostname
PowerShell exited with code '1'

This message is returned by the jdbc driver. You may need to add at least the database name to your db url, like in jdbc:db2://hostname/MY_DATABASE . You can find more parameters here.
